# Can Bower resolve recursive dependencies correctly?

Tags: polymer, bower

I'm trying to create a package containing "Polymer/polymer" and "Polymer/core-elements" both having specific version 0.3.5.

```
$ cat bower.json 
{
  "name": "bower-test",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#0.3.5",
    "core-elements": "Polymer/core-elements#0.3.5"
  },
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ]
}

$ bower --version
1.3.10
```

When I try to install the dependencies, bower reports about conflicts in `polymer` version resolution:

```
$ bower install
bower not-cached    git://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#0.3.5
bower resolve       git://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#0.3.5
bower not-cached    git://github.com/Polymer/core-elements.git#0.3.5
bower resolve       git://github.com/Polymer/core-elements.git#0.3.5
bower download      https://github.com/Polymer/core-elements/archive/0.3.5.tar.gz
bower download      https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/archive/0.3.5.tar.gz
bower extract       core-elements#0.3.5 archive.tar.gz
bower invalid-meta  core-elements is missing "main" entry in bower.json
bower invalid-meta  core-elements is missing "ignore" entry in bower.json
bower resolved      git://github.com/Polymer/core-elements.git#0.3.5
bower not-cached    git://github.com/Polymer/core-ajax.git#>=0.3.0 <1.0.0
bower resolve       git://github.com/Polymer/core-ajax.git#>=0.3.0 <1.0.0
-------------------------- skipped -------------------------------------
bower download      https://github.com/Polymer/core-ajax/archive/0.4.0.tar.gz
-------------------------- skipped -------------------------------------
bower not-cached    git://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#>=0.4.0 <1.0.0
bower resolve       git://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#>=0.4.0 <1.0.0
-------------------------- skipped -------------------------------------
bower download      https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/archive/0.4.0.tar.gz

Unable to find a suitable version for polymer, please choose one:
    1) polymer#>=0.3.0 <1.0.0 which resolved to 0.3.5 and is required by core-elements#0.3.5, core-layout#0.3.5 
    2) polymer#0.3.5 which resolved to 0.3.5 and is required by bower-test 
    3) polymer#>=0.4.0 <1.0.0 which resolved to 0.4.0 and is required by core-ajax#0.4.0, core-animated-pages#0.4.0, core-animation#0.4.0, core-collapse#0.4.0, core-component-page#0.4.0, core-dropdown#0.4.0, core-field#0.4.0, core-header-panel#0.4.0, core-icons#0.4.0, core-iconset#0.4.0, core-iconset-svg#0.4.0, core-input#0.4.0, core-layout-grid#0.4.0, core-layout-trbl#0.4.0, core-list#0.4.0, core-localstorage#0.4.0, core-media-query#0.4.0, core-menu-button#0.4.0, core-meta#0.4.0, core-overlay#0.4.0, core-popup-menu#0.4.0, core-range#0.4.0, core-selection#0.4.0, core-selector#0.4.0, core-shared-lib#0.4.0, core-signals#0.4.0, core-splitter#0.4.0, core-style#0.4.0, core-tooltip#0.4.0, core-transition#0.4.0, marked-element#0.4.0, prettify-element#0.4.0
```

[Full log](http://pastebin.com/HvFKYdJt)

If I understand things right, that is what bower does:

1. Fetches `core-elements#0.3.5`
2. Sees that `core-elements#0.3.5` depends on `core-ajax#>=0.3.0`
3. Fetches a **latest** version of `core-ajax` which is `core-ajax#0.4.0`
4. Sees that `core-ajax#0.4.0` depends on `polymer#>=0.4.0`
5. Reports an error, because we specified exact version `0.3.5` for `polymer` in `bower.json`.

A valid configuration for dependencies does exist (take `core-ajax#0.3.5`, which depends on `polymer#>=0.3.5`), however bower is not able to find such configuration. Worse, it doesn't even try.

Am I doing something wrong? If not, is there some solution?

Comment: In general, if Bower can't figure out how to resolve the version of a resource, it will prompt you like this. The reason it's prompting you in this case is because you've chose an exact version `#0.3.5` in your bower.json. If you relaxed that a bit things my resolve by themselves (e.g. `>=0.3.5 <1.0.0`. Is there a reason why you can't use 0.4.0 so everything resolves to the latest version?

Comment: @ebidel, there are several users of Polymer (only polymer itself, not including any components) in my project, and the current version of Polymer used in the project is `0.3.5`. That's why I can't update Polymer to higher version easily (especially to the next major version). Dependencies section of bower.json contains only one line now: `"polymer": "Polymer/polymer#0.3.5"`. I want to bring polymer components to the project, so I added `Polymer/core-elements#0.3.5` to the dependencies list, expecting this will work.

Comment: We sync'd offline. For everyone else, there doesn't seem to be a good way to do this. The `>=0.3.5 <1.0.0` in core-element's bower.json is pretty loose about what it resolves to. If you want exact versions for everything, you have to enumerate the list of element deps in your own bower.json :(